# Drop down list to show values from another sheet except the first row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Sheet A with column LOCATION whose drop down should come from Sheet B. The problem is that the HEADER in SHEET B should not come in drop down. The drop down in Sheet A should have values like HOLDING, IND001 and so on. Also sheet B can have n number of rows which would change dynamically. I tried to put in data validation like `=LOCATION!$C:$C` however it brings the HEADER LOCATION as well in the dropdown which is incorrect.

SHEET A
[image: sheet a]

SHEET B
[image: sheet b]

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV Microsoft Office 365 Pro Plus , excel version is 2002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NameManager` and data validation.

1. First create a name manager with name `MyLocation` with below formula.

   `=OFFSET(LOCATION!$C$2,,,COUNTA(LOCATION!$C$2:$C$2000))`

[image]

2. Then use that name to data validation like below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this done. Can you please explain what does C$2000 refer to in the formula? If possible can you elaborate the logic behind the formula?